# Puppeteer Firebase Cloud Function doesn't work when deployed

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that utilizes Puppeteer to scrape data from a website and return an array of data. The function works perfectly on my local machine, but when deployed to Firebase, it returns an empty object.

Here are the relevant code snippets that cause the problem:

The Main Firebase function:

```js
export const extractDailyTechnicalsTest2 = functions
  .runWith({ memory: "8GB", timeoutSeconds: 540 })
  .pubsub.schedule("0 0 * * *")
  .timeZone("Asia/Dubai")
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: "new",
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(2 * 60 * 1000);
    try {
      const actions = await extractTechnicalActionsTradingView(page);
      console.log("Success");
      console.log("Actions:", actions);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error: ", error);
      console.log("An error occurred");
    }
  });
```

And the helper scraping function:

```js
async function extractTechnicalActionsTradingView(page) {
  await page.goto(`https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/ADX-DRIVE/technicals/`, {
    waitUntil: "load",
  });

  const data1d = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll(".row-hvDpy38G");

    // Extract data for the first 6 oscillators
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      const row = rows[i];
      const name = row
        .querySelector(".cell-hvDpy38G:nth-child(1)")
        .textContent.trim();
      const action = row
        .querySelector(".cell-hvDpy38G:nth-child(3)")
        .textContent.trim();

      data.push({ name, action });
    }

    return data;
  });

  return data1d;
}
```

The above code combined is a complete minimal reproducible example.

I'm expecting the function to log the scraped data as such:

```
Actions: [
  { name: 'Relative Strength Index (14)', action: 'Neutral' },
  { name: 'Stochastic %K (14, 3, 3)', action: 'Neutral' },
  ...
]
```

But gets an empty object instead:
[image: Empty object log - Google cloud]

I've tried different versions of Puppeteer (20.9.0, 18.0.0, 21.6.1, 16.2.0), and all of them worked on my laptop. Some versions required Chromium when deployed, so I added the following to my `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "gcp-build": "node node_modules/puppeteer/install.js"
}
```

This resolved the issue of missing Chromium, but the function still returns empty objects when deployed.

I've checked the Cloud Functions logs, and there are no error messages. The function completes successfully, but the data is not being extracted as expected.

Any insights into why this might be happening or suggestions for debugging would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a lot of code here, but no clear description of what specifically in all this doesn't work the way you expect.  You should trim the example down to the bare minimum and do some debugging to find out which line of code is the problem, then edit the question to be more precise.

Comment: Hopefully, it's clearer @DougStevenson

Comment: It's not clear.  What do you mean by "the functions returns empty objects"?  As far as I can see, the function doesn't "return" anything at all.  What exactly is empty?  Also there are a lot of functions calls here that you're not showing, so we don't really know what this code is doing.  You need to prove a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) that anyone can run to reproduce the same behavior that you observe.

Comment: @HadiEl-Amin I use Puppeteer in a Firebase Cloud Function also. I compared my code to yours, and I don't see anything obviously wrong with how you are initializing Puppeteer or opening the page. If this was my function, I'd try grabbing a simpler element from the page or a different page first to verify that works. If it does, then I'd add debugging statements at every single step to try to figure out what works vs. where it is breaking. I cannot tell for sure from the URL you are using, but one other possibility is that the content you are seeking is appearing after the page loads.

Comment: @most200 Thanks for your recommendation, My issue is that the code runs perfectly well on my machine extracting everything, I'm suspecting its a compatibility issue with GCP, However, I'll do more debugging and hopefully everything works out.

Comment: @most200 Hey, I still have no luck with it, can you please show me your package.json? What puppeteer version are you using, I suspect it to be a compatibility issue.

Comment: @HadiEl-Amin I deployed your code to a test function in my project, and the code works fine. It returns the actions as expected. My package.json is using puppeteer 15.5.0. There are several other Stack Overflow questions/answers that discuss downgrading puppeteer to make it work with Cloud Functions. It has been a while since I set it up, and I don't remember why I settled on 15.5.0, but it must be because that is what worked for my functions.

Comment: Additional note: my test with your code and my own functions that utilize puppeteer are all https.onRequest functions. Your original code is for a pubsub function. I don't know why that would matter, but sometimes Cloud Functions do unexpected things. I would try downgrading your puppeteer to 15.5.0 and also test it in an onRequest function to verify.